# How can I optimize this query that contains two subqueries and a union so it runs faster?

Tags: sql, optimization, subquery, union

How can I optimize this query? It is taking over 10 minutes to run and the temp table it is being run on is only 1.4 million records.

```
select [Condition, Specimen container, Testing Laboratory (Unit only)], [Condition, Specimen container, STAT Laboratory (STAT only)], [Date Specimen Collected],[Specimen Source Type], [Material Submitted], [Specimen source site], * 
from  #TMP_CLIA_EXPORT_ACTIVE
WHERE DEPT = '71'
AND [Date Specimen Collected] IS NULL
OR CUID IN (SELECT CUID FROM #TMP_CLIA_EXPORT_ACTIVE
            WHERE [Condition, Specimen container, STAT Laboratory (STAT only)] IS NULL
            AND [Condition, Specimen container, Testing Laboratory (Unit only)] IS NULL)
OR CUID IN (SELECT CUID FROM #TMP_CLIA_EXPORT_ACTIVE 
            WHERE [Specimen Source Type] IS NULL 
            AND [Material Submitted] IS NULL
            AND [Specimen source site] IS NULL)
            
union all

select [Condition, Specimen container, Testing Laboratory (Unit only)], [Condition, Specimen container, STAT Laboratory (STAT only)], [Date Specimen Collected],[Specimen Source Type], [Material Submitted], [Specimen source site], *
from #TMP_CLIA_EXPORT_ARCHIVE
WHERE DEPT = '71'
AND [Date Specimen Collected] IS NULL
OR CUID IN (SELECT CUID FROM #TMP_CLIA_EXPORT_ACTIVE
            WHERE [Condition, Specimen container, STAT Laboratory (STAT only)] IS NULL
            AND [Condition, Specimen container, Testing Laboratory (Unit only)] IS NULL)
OR CUID IN (SELECT CUID FROM #TMP_CLIA_EXPORT_ACTIVE 
            WHERE [Specimen Source Type] IS NULL 
            AND [Material Submitted] IS NULL
            AND [Specimen source site] IS NULL)
```

Comment: You have no parentheses in your where clause.  With ors, that's probably a bad idea.  If you only want rows where  `DEPT = '71'`, then limit what goes into the temp table based on that.  In addition, your two selects look identical, although it's hard to say with those giant column names.  Do you really have a column named `[Condition, Specimen container, STAT Laboratory (STAT only)]`?

Comment: The queries appear identical - is the actual intention to duplicate all rows?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? The above query is product specific.

Answer (score 0):

The following queries do the same job. But the 2nd query returns faster. Maybe it will work for you.

Query 1 ;

```
SELECT Bolge,
       Ulke,
       Baskent FROM Ulkeler WHERE Baskent IN
     (SELECT Sehir
      FROM Sehirler) -- 1st Sub Query
     AND Baskent IN
     (SELECT Sehir   -- 2nd Sub Query
      FROM Sehirler
      WHERE Nufus2017 > 1000000);
```

[Query 1 elapsed time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvphL.jpg)

Query 2 ;

```
SELECT Bolge,
       Ulke,
       Baskent
FROM Ulkeler U
WHERE EXISTS
      (SELECT 1
       FROM Sehirler S
       WHERE U.Baskent = S.Sehir
             AND Nufus2017 > 1000000);
```

[Query 2 elapsed time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hqr2Y.jpg)